# Where is Gehenom located?

Tags: talmud-bavli, literalism, afterlife, gehinnom, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

Where is Gehenom located? After Korach and his followers got swallowed up by the Earth, they fell right outside the gates of Gehenom, and are (presumably) till this day yelling משה אמת ותורתו אמת (Baba Batra 74a).

I also heard a story about an Israeli soldier who found a hole that lead deep into the Earth (in either the Negev or Sinai desert) and heard the said phrase, understanding it to be from Korach and his followers. These sources *seems* to imply that Gehenom is seen as physical place inside the Earth.  Do some people actually hold that Gehenom is inside and a part of the Earth?

Comment: Pretty sure Gehenom was a real place where people were buried in the past. As far as people being standard there, I don’t think thats verifiable. Perhaps it is a parable.

Comment: You mean גיא בן הינום, where child sacrifices happened?

Comment: No, because Jews never sacrificed humans. We don’t believe in it.

Comment: A burial place sounds more like it.

Comment: @Turk Jews doing things Judaism doesn't believe in has indeed never happened. Ever.

Comment: @DoubleAA That’s what I said. Jews never preform child sacrifices. In fact, it was the Jews who brought morality into the world, saying each life is made in the”image of G-d.”

Comment: @Turk Hill ok .

Comment: @TurkHill So what, if not Jews, were the "_people of Judah_" who "_built the shrines of Topheth in the Valley of Ben-hinnom to burn their sons and daughters in fire_" ([Jer. 7:30-1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.7.30?lang=bi&lang2=en))?

Comment: @TamirEvan I think they were some Jews who went astray, but the majority, or at least those who followed the Torah, were alarmed to human sacrifices. They adored G-d, nestled in Torah study.

Comment: @TamirEvan I agree that sacrificing children did occur, even in Isreal, but as you well know, (assuming you are Jewish) child sacrifice, indeed human sacrifice is prohibited according to Mosaic law.

Comment: @TamirEvan Again, child sacrifices happened in Greece, Rome, Egypt, India, Persia,  China, and Israel is no exception, however, observant Jews (Torah-driven Jews) did not preform child sacrifices because Mosaic law prohibited it. That is to say, that the Torah condemns child sacrifices. Some Jews went astray and worshiped the gods of the pagans who demanded child sacrifices.

Comment: For example, take Chapter 22 Akedah (Abraham’s binding/near-sacrifice of Isaac), was a custom that many cultures did in the Middle East at that time. All pagans preforms this ritual.

Comment: According to the Bible, G-d spoke to Abraham and he would have killed Isaac were it not for an intervention of an angel shouting to stop. However, this story should not be taken literally. Think of Jacob wrestling with Esau or an angel in his dream. Similarly, G-d did not actually speak. Abraham didn’t hear G-d’s voice but his own resolve. It was day-time thinking. Abraham was wondering: should he follow the teachings of the masses and kill Isaac?

Comment: At first, Abraham thought maybe the pagans were right. But soon Abraham understood that human sacrifice is wrong, realizing that G-d does not desire the death of innocent children. G-d is just, merciful, gracious, loving. G-d is the opposite of brutality, the way of the pagans.

Comment: Interestingly, until the Torah revealed the moment of realization, the Torah employs the generic name for G-d, Elohim, G-d. But once in the moment of realization, the Torah switch to the name to y-h-v-h, the G-d of Israel.

Comment: What are you guys arguing about? Gey ben Hinom was a place outside Yerushalyem where off the derech pagan יהודים sacrificed their kids to their foolish idols , and of course not in accordance with the Torah. Also @Turk how do you know what Avraham Avinu (עליו השלום) thought?

Comment: Re: the account in [Baba Batra 74a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.74a.5?lang=bi&lang2=he): It seem to belong to the stories of [Rabbah bar bar Hana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbah_bar_bar_Hana) of the wondrous things he saw and experienced in his travels. To the best of my knowledge, these stories are usually interpreted non-literally (even with Rav Papa bar Samuel remarking about one of them, "Had I not been there I would not have believed it").

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in Eiruvin 19a brings from Rav Yirmiyahu Ben Elazar who explains that there are 3 different entrances to gehenom. One entrance is located in the desert which swallowed up Korach and his family. The second location is in the sea,and the 3rd location is in Jerusalem.

The gemara then asks is there really only 3 openings? Dont we say that gehenom is in the valley of Ven Hinom and smoke rises between two date palm trees? The gemara answers that this entrance may be the entrance in Jerusalem and there would be no contradiction to the number 3.

From the reading of the gemara it seems that gehenom is very possibly inside the earth since Korach got swallowed up into the earth ,and the gemara says that is the entrance to gehenom of the desert.

In the Sefer Bais Yisroel Hashalem 8:pg.250 that near har hazeisim there is a house of worship of the Notzrim which stands right on top of the entrance of gehenom.

In Masheches Tamid 32 it brings from Tanna Devei Eliyahu who says that gehenom is in the sky,and some say it is beyond the mountain of darkness.

The Zohar Terumah 150 writes that there are 7 openings to gehenom.

All info can be found in Sefer Shaar Reuvein pg.427.

Comment: So are we presuming it's an actual physical location within the earth as opposed to a location on a supernatural plane like heaven for instance?

Comment: So the Russian "Church of Mary Magdalene" is directly on top of Gehinom??

Comment: @KapinKrunch , I remember thinking of that as possibility ,but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Heaven and hell are literally on earth in this world.

> ...הַגַּן־עֵדֶן וְהַגֵּיהִנֹּם הֵם בְּזֶה הָעוֹלָם מַמָּשׁ
>   Gan Eden and Geyhinom are on this world *mamash* (tangibly)...

--Likutei Moharan #22, beg. of last paragraph[1]

[1] https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.22.21.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Can you eleborate more on this subject

Comment: For example "Whoever gets angry, all kinds of Gehinnom rule over him," R"L (Nedarim 22a).  
But one who abandons the world to a sufficient extent, delving in only Avodath Hashem in prayer, hitbodedut (private conversation-contemplation-time with H`, best done in nature where people don't go), settling his Daat considering what is the True Purpose, learning (some halakhah daily and especially books of the Zohar H"K etc.), mitzvot, friends Shabbatot chagim, etc. -- can feel Gan Eden here.  If he feels it here and it's real what difference "where."

Comment: Interesting. I remember R' Nachman also said something similarly about ותחזינה עינינו בשובך לציון ברחמים. but gehenom is still a real place where reshaim and others are severly punished (in many cases, this lasts for eternity R"L)

Comment: You're right re it's also a real place; see the rest of that ref. in LM #22 where he z"l says: but it's impossible to get there due to the extreme cold in the north and south.  In other discussions he's addressing the aspect of suffering in this world and in that regard Gehinom is right here on earth, plus embarrassment is even worse and even in the Future "every tzaddik will be singed [embarrassed] by this fellow's [greater] chuppah" (discussed there).

Comment: See also LM Part 2 #119 -- ...הִנֵּה הַכֹּל אוֹמְרִים, שֶׁיֵּשׁ עוֹלָם הַזֶּה וְעוֹלָם הַבָּא. וְהִנֵּה עוֹלָם הַבָּא – אָנוּ מַאֲמִינִים שֶׁיֵּשׁ עוֹלָם הַבָּא, אֶפְשָׁר יֵשׁ גַּם עוֹלָם הַזֶּה גַּם־כֵּן בְּאֵיזֶה עוֹלָם, כִּי בְּכָאן נִרְאֶה שֶׁהוּא הַגֵּיהִנֹּם, כִּי כֻלָּם מְלֵאִים יִסּוּרִים גְּדוֹלִים תָּמִיד.  We should ask does *this* world really exist, because here it looks like hell!
https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan%2C_Part_II.119.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en